# Why does delete not work on full_messages function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have the following code:

```
def register_learner
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @registation = EventRegistration.new first_name: params[:first_name], last_name: params[:last_name], email: params[:email], event_id: params[:event_id]

  if !@registation.valid?
    @registation.errors.full_messages.delete("Event has already been taken"
    flash[:notice] = @registation.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    redirect_to(event_path(@event))
  else
    @registation.save
  end
end
```

Note the line `@registation.errors.full_messages.delete("Event has already been taken")` where I am trying to delete this particular message from the full_messages array, however it does not work. The next line is the flash message, and the message "Event has already been taken" is still being displayed.

Here is a sanity check via the console...

```
2.1.5 :001 > errors = ["Event has already been taken", "Last name can't be blank"]
 => ["Event has already been taken", "Last name can't be blank"]
2.1.5 :002 > errors.delete "Event has already been taken"
 => "Event has already been taken"
2.1.5 :003 > errors
 => ["Last name can't be blank"]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `full_messages` is a method, which gerneates a new array every time you call it. To do what you want:

```
errors = @registation.errors.full_messages
errors.delete("Event has already been taken")
flash[:notice] = errors.to_sentence
```

That answers the question, now there is a matter of - why do you need to do this? There might be a better way.

In general relying on strings is usually a bad idea, imagine that in a half a year you will need to change an error message for this validation. Can you be 100% sure you will remember to change it here as well? If not, you have a bug.

Comment: Thanks Bro. Yeah, I agree its wonky. Its a specific request where we want the validation to keep the DB clean, but we don't want to throw an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Well, because Rails re-creates `#full_messages` using `errors` every time you call the method:

```
def full_messages(options = {})
  @errors.values.inject([]) do |full_messages, errors|
    full_messages + errors.map { |error| error.full_message }
  end
end
```

[Source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html#M001735)

You can use `#select` to skip that message:

```
@registation.errors.full_messages.select{|x| x != "Event has already been taken"}.to_sentence
```

Also, you can use `#delete` on `#errors.messages` (not `full_messages`), because they are exposed attribute of the underlying object (not a copy, as with full_messages):

```
@registration.errors.messages[:event].delete('has already been taken')
```